# Internet download speed slow on laptop but runs normally on mobile

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, internet-speed

System OS: Windows 10 Pro

My ISP offers 50 Mbps speed but whenever I run speed test on laptop, it shows 4-5 Mbps but when I do the same on mobile it shows 34 Mbps. I tried troubleshooting few things like updating WiFi drivers though it shows I have latest drivers, resetting my router(DLink 802.11 b/g/n), changing channels on router settings but didn't work. I have been facing this issue from quite some time.

Comment: How is the actual download speed on laptop regardless of what's reported by speed-tests? Try downgrading drivers on Laptop. Do mention the OS on laptop, if Windows 7/8/10, go to Device Manager and do a rollback of WiFi drivers and see if it helps. Sometimes I find that the default Window 10 drivers might perform better than the vendor provided latest. If possible try booting the Laptop thru live Linux or some third-party live Windows rescue USB/DVD and connect to WiFi and re-test the speed.

Comment: I am using Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: @patkim when I installed bit defender professional(got the key from some YouTube video) antivirus on my laptop, it became more slow. You think there is a problem with antivirus tool? or do I need to rollback drivers?

Comment: I suggest you edit your question and provide therein all relevant information that you have provided in the comments so far like OS, Software Installs, what you suspect etc. If you suspect Antivirus being the issue, then you should try disabling or uninstalling it and check again!

Comment: Sounds like a difference between MBps and Mbps or Mibps. Are you sure you're using the right acronyms/abbreviations at each of the totals you've noted?

Comment: If your PC has an Ethernet cable, try plugging it in and trying the test. This could help determine if the problem us related to av or your WiFi interface.

Comment: @l3l_aze yes I know those differences

Comment: @davidgo I don't have Ethernet cable at the moment. I checked the speed by connecting the cable provided by my ISP to my laptop. I see the speed differs every time I run a speed test like 20, 30 and sometimes 40 Mbps which is far better than 4-5 Mbps.

Comment: It sounds to me like you might have more then 1 issue. To limit issues, buy an Ethernet cable (from a dollar store is fine) - then eliminate non-wifi issues, then tackle WiFi.   Also can you advise what chipset your Ethernet card and WiFi module use. (I'm guessing it will be Realtek for WiFi - Realtek is as common as it is cheap and sucky. The exact model might be useful)

Comment: I'd also try another couple of things - try reducing the MTU on your Ethernet device to say 1476 and see if that fixes anything. Also, if you know how to do so safely (Linux iso's?) Try using p2p app and see what the performance is like. This is useful because it opens lots of threads, and can speak to packet loss by your ISP - which could explain your very variable Ethernet tests.

Comment: @davidgo: Its Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller and version 10.26.328.2018

Comment: @davidgo I sent out a ping request to reduce MTU until I got 0% packet loss. It didn't help though in terms of Internet speed?

Comment: @davidgo I set the MTU to 1470 in my router settings as am getting the reply from a url. But I don't see any change in speed :(

Comment: @Krish - from what you have written its not an MTU issue.   One of the factors is likely the crap WIFI card your system has.  I don't know much about them or their support in Windows, but have learnt they are real bad news in Linux systems.  I just replace them with useable stuff instead.   You may have other problems as well though.

Comment: @davidgo do you think if I buy any WIFI card separately n fix it in my laptop, would it work fine? do you have suggestions as to what WIFI card to buy?

Comment: I think that is likely but can't guarantee it - and as I said, I suspect you have more then 1 issue. I'd be getting an Ethernet cable and making sure that works fine.  Intel make good WiFi (and ethernet) chips and I would use one with that chipset.

Comment: @davidgo Checked with Ethernet cable - am getting the desired speed - as you said, "eliminate non-wifi issues, then tackle WiFi" - can you just provide step by step as to how to do this?

Comment: How far from the router is the computer?   Does the router support 5g and if so are you connected on 5g?  It does sound like replacing the wifibcard will improve things a lot.

Comment: Router and PC are in same room(almost close). No, router supports only single band. As you only said we can't guarantee it works fine. Which WIFI card would be better if I have to buy for this model Dell Inspiron 3542?

Comment: @davidgo what do you say?

Comment: I'm not comfortable making a specific recommendation (I don't have that laptop, and there are different form factors),  I comment that my similar vintage Dell Venue 11 came with an Intel card and I'm very happy with it. If you are comfortable sharing it, what is the service tag of your unit (which will let me look at the current card model and may be helpful in determining the form factor)

Comment: Alternatively, consider a USB WiFi adaptor.

Comment: @davidgo btw how do I find out the service tag of it without removing the hardware? I can mail the service tag number if you could provide your email id?

Comment: @davidgo I don't want to use any USB's.

Comment: @krish the service tag is normally located with the serial number at the back of the device.  There are other ways -  https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-us/sln298441/how-to-find-the-product-model-of-your-dell-computer We don't share emails here, and service tags don't tell you anything about ownership except purchase date and warranty (but includes detailed device specs).

Comment: If you don't want to disclose it, go to https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us and enter your tag. Go to Parts and accessories and provide the output of that, or find the line describing the WiFi card and advise the part number and description. That will allow us to check the interface is the correct one.

Comment: @davidgo Clicked Parts and accessories, I didn't see a WIFI card. I checked all categories. All I see Ethernet cables but no WIFI card?

Comment: @davidgo Send the service tag to the above mail id. Please check.

Comment: As per our private communication, your Dell service tag reveals the following of relevance - 555-BBCB : DW 1705 + BT4.0 [802.11bgn + B luetooth 4.0, 2.4 GHz, 1x1]  and describes part C3Y4J - CRD,WRLES,HMC,DW1705BN,WW,FXCN.  This means the current WIFI card (assuming its not been changed after it left the factory) is one like https://www.amazon.com/Dell-Wireless-Bluetooth-Half-Height-Mini-PCI/dp/B00UX2Z1OK - so you want a Half-Height Mini-PCI Express Card.

Comment: The Amazon "Customers who viewed this item also viewed" section has a number of cards which could be a good replacement - If it were me I'd go for an Intel 7260 based card with Bluetooth like https://www.amazon.com/Intel-7260-HMWG-R-Wireless-AC-Network-adapter/dp/B00MV3N7UO

Comment: @davidgo I don't know what is wrong with my existing WiFi card. It's not been changed anytime.

Comment: @davidgo do you think by replacing with a new WiFi card(Intel 7260) would increase my Internet speed?

Comment: I can't guarantee this but it is highly likely. For a start (on the n band) the Dell card has a theoretical limit of 150 megabit while the Intel one is 300 megabit. (Whether this helps depends on your router.). The Intel board almost certainly has better sensitivity because its newer and this is important. Likewise, the driver support for Intel is better, and I am pretty sure the design as well. (I'm not sure if the old card is atheros or realtek, but if its the same as one that came in my old, replaced dell laptop, its an atheros card with an unusual method of communicating using gpio. )

Comment: @davidgo from Amazon.in website could you recommend similar to Intel 7260. Couldn't find it in Amazon.in.

Comment: Seriously?  I linked to Amazon in my original advice. A search for "Aliexpress 7260 wifi" also revealed a plethora of cards there

Comment: @davidgo one last time. Don't mind me. Do I need to have a dual band router in order to get this Intel 7260 card? I have a single band router.

Comment: @krish No, you don't need a dual band router to get this card - although the card would perform better if you had one.  The reason to look to this card even when you have a low spec router is that the card is newer, and thus likely more sensitive to signal then your existing one.   It probably also has better drivers.  Any "AC' standard card will work on an an 802.11n network.